# I am new to rally and SDK. I would like to create a custom page such that it would give a list of User stories along with test case status

Tags: rally

Say,

If i have 3 user stories, 
the grid should display 3 US along with test case status right side in same column. 
i am working on it to create it.
But if any one have an idea, it would be very helpful me to look into and learn.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same column to contain values from different fields, use `renderer` function.
There is an example of it in this [github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/stories-with-tasks) where 4 different fields values are displayed in the Task column

```
{
    text: 'Tasks', dataIndex: 'Tasks', minWidth: 150,
         renderer: function(value) {
             var html = [];
                 _.each(value, function(task){
                      html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(task) + '">' + task.FormattedID + '</a>' + ' State: ' + task.State + ' Estimate:' + task.Estimate +  ' ToDo:' + task.ToDo);
                  });
               return html.join('</br>');
           }
},
```